# Repeating a function with a 1 second interval a certain number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, sleep

So, I'm working on a timer and this is my code right now:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

function timerCreate() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sleep(1000);
    minusOneSec();
  }
}
```

All I wanted to do was that ten times, every one second, the minusOneSec() function was executed. (I took the code for the sleep() function from an answer I saw in StackOverflow some time ago and I don't remember who came up with it so if you know please tell me so I can credit them.) It works, but now it has come to my atention that this sleep function will stop all java script in the page while it's running. Is this true? What I also tried was this:

```
function timerCreate() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setInterval(minusOneSec, 1000);
  }
}
```

but what it did was to run the minusOneSec() function 10 times in a row, then wait one second, then the function 10 times in a row, and so on. Is there a way to do what I intended but allowing other javascript code to run at the same time? I can use jQuery if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setInterval()` just once (instead of in a loop) and check the counter inside. `setInterval()` will keep executing the passed function, till we clear the interval.

```
var i = 0, 
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        minusOneSec();
        i++;
        if(i >= 10) clearInterval(interval); // stop it
    }, 1000);
```